# I want to trigger Power Automate when a retention label is applied. Is there any third party connector or workaround for the same?

Tags: sharepoint, power-automate

I want to trigger Power Automate on applying a retention label to copy a file from one document library to another.

I am currently trying a flow with the trigger "When file is created or modified" and then applying the condition that flow should run when value of column "Item is a Record" will be "Yes". But unfortunately, the flow is not triggering on applying the retention label.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently MS Flow (Power Automate) don't have this capability to Get/Set the compliance labels (Retention/Sensitivity).

If we need MS to prioritize the availability of Trigger/Action in Flow, please [vote this idea](https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/Power-Automate-Ideas/Get-and-Set-Compliance-Labels-in-SharePoint/idi-p/156112).